# Minifed JS not working with Audio?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

So, I have this issue where when I use this code,

```
var song = new Audio('music.mp3');
song.volume = 0.25;
song.autoLoop = true;
song.play();
```

It loops the audio when it's done playing, but when I use this minified code,
(new lines for readability)

```
var e=new Audio("music.mp3");
e.volume=.25,
e.autoLoop=!0,
e.play();
```

It doesn't autoloop.

I know !0 is true and I don't see why it's not working.

Edit: I changed it to .loop and it worked as well as autLoop. idk

Comment: there is no `autoLoop` property, did you mean `loop`? Using the correct property name will probably fix your problem

Comment: The weird thing is that Dimid says that it works when its not minified. :/

Comment: If changing it didnt work, you will need to show a working example of the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a longshot but try changing the commas to semicolons on e.volume and e.autoLoop. Also, if you know that !0 is true then why not just set it to true? Is it supposed to be != 0 ?

Comment: It's minified code, minifiers try to reduce as much text as possible to keep filesize down, so true become !0 as its 2 characters less

Comment: Nice, that makes sense. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score -2):

Try picking a different variable name - e could be being misinterpreted as an event